# Plot the speed of the proton against magnetic field in Python

Tags: python, plot, physics

I have been trying to plot the linear speed of the proton against magnetic field. The proton is moving in a circular orbit in an
uniform magnetic field perpendicular to the velocity. The radius of the orbit changes from 14 cm to 8 cm when the uniform magnetic field increases from 0.35 T to 2 T.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants
p  = 1.6
q  = scipy.constants.e 
p_mass    = scipy.constants.proton_mass

B_List = []
r_List = []
v_List = []
for r in np.linspace (0.14, 0.08):
    for B in np.linspace (0.35, 2):
        v = (r*q*B)/p_mass  
        B_List.append(B)
        v_List.append(v)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(B_List,v_List)
fig.suptitle('Linear Speed Vs Magnatic Field', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Magnatic field (T)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Speed of the Proton (m/s)', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

For some reasons, I got a multiple lines on the graph.

[image]

I tried to make the spaces = 2 (in linspace) as follows:

```
for r in np.linspace (0.14, 0.08,2, 2):
for B in np.linspace (0.35, 2, 2):
```

but still, those multiple lines are appearing.

My question here, how to get rid of those lines?

Comment: Well you get a line for each `r` which is exactly what one would expect. What kind of result do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you use the `plot` function in `pyplot` to show your points. That function draws line segments between consecutive plotted points.

Instead, use the `scatter` function, which just shows the points without any connecting line segments. When I replace `plot` with `scatter`, I get the result below. Click on the graphic to see it full size--then you will see that each of those apparent vertical line segments are actually 50 points close together. That seems to be correct, though there are no circular paths that you mention. Is that what you want?

[image]

Comment: I want the plot to look like a linear relation between v and B. I mean, just a single line to show this correlation, not a multiple points.

This is what I want to get:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501294725400

Comment: I cannot load the photo that you link--I get a logon dialog box. And there is no simple "linear relation between `v` and `B`" since the equation for `v` also has `r` in it which changes. For a single `r` you do get a linear relation. The dots at the top of each vertical set of dots are the linear relation for `r=0.14` and the bottom dots are the linear relation for `r=0.08` and the other dots are for other values of `r`. The lines in your original plot are the linear relations for each `r`--I though you wanted to get rid of them?